# Recorrer Divs con bucle python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hola espero puedan ayudarme.

estoy realizando Web Scripting con python y selenium.
quiero pasarme al siguiente Div, realmente no se si estan en una lista.
quiero realizar algo asi:

```
pc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/main/section/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]')

i=1
while i < ndc:
    print("CANCION:",i)
    cancion = driver.find_element(pc)[+i]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", cancion)
    pc=cancion
    i=i+1
    sleep(random.uniform(20.0,30.0))
```

donde  el `[+1]` seria el siguiente div,
realmente no entiendo si esta en una lista o en algo que lo pueda identificar solo se me ocurre por posición.

gracias.

Answer (score 0):

elementos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-tile__item")
for elemento in elementos:
print(elemento.text)

## seleccionas el selector con todos los elementos luegos los recorres y que te muestre por cada elemento recorrido el elemento que quieres obtener